# I can't find CloudWatch metric in Grafana UI query editor/builder

Tags: grafana

I'm trying to create a Grafana dashboard that will reflect my AWS RDS cluster metrics.
For the simplicity I've chose CloudWatch as a datasource, It works well for showing the 'direct' metrics from the RDS cluster.

Problem is that we've switched to use RDS Proxy due the high number of connections we are required to support.

Now, I'm adjusting my dashboard to reflect few metrics that are lacking, most important is number of actual connections, which in AWS CloudWatch console presented by this query:

```
SELECT AVG(DatabaseConnections) 
FROM SCHEMA("AWS/RDS", ProxyName,Target,TargetGroup) 
WHERE Target = 'db:my-db-1' 
AND ProxyName = 'my-db-rds-proxy' 
AND TargetGroup = 'default'
```

Problem is that I can't find it anywhere in the CloudWatch Grafana query editor:
[image]
The only metric with "connections" is the standard `DatabaseConnections` which represents the 'direct' connections to the RDS cluster and not the connections to the RDS Proxy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain `I can't find it anywhere in the CloudWatch Grafana datasource`, pls?

Comment: @JanGaraj I've added a screenshot to emphasis where I'm searching for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So for who ever will ever get here you should use `ClientConnections` and use the `ProxyName` as the dimension (which I didn't set initially
[image]

I was using old Grafana version (7.3.5) which didn't have it built in.

Answer (score 2):

That UI editor is generated from [hardcoded list of metrics](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/v9.3.2/pkg/tsdb/cloudwatch/constants/metrics.go), which may not contain all metrics and dimensions (especially if they have been added recently), so in that case UI doesn't generate them in the selectbox.

But that is not a problem, because that selectbox is not a standard selectbox. It is an input, where you can write your own metric and dimension name. Just click there, write what you need and `Hit enter to add` (the same is applicable for:

[image]

**Pro tip**: don't use UI query builder (that's for beginners), but switch to `Code` and write your queries directly (anyway UI builder builds that query under the hood):

[image]

It would be nice if you create a Grafana PR - add these metrics and dimensions which are missing in the UI builder to `metrics.go`.